# Minkowski Functional differential

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I have a question about Minkowski functional.

We start with a compact, convex set $C$ containing $0$ in its interior. We define the Minkowski functional of $C$ to be the function $\mu: R^n \to [0,\infty)$ given by the formula 
\begin{eqnarray} 
\mu _C(x) &:=& \min\{\lambda ; \lambda^{-1}x \in C\}\\
\mu_C (0) &: =& 0.
\end{eqnarray}

Assume now that the boundary $\Sigma$ of $C$ is a $C^2$ hypersurface. Then $\mu_C$ is $C^2$ at every point $x \neq 0$ in $R^n$.

Now my question, how can I check that
 \begin{equation}
\mu_C'(x) = x\|x\|^{-1}, \;\; \text{for}\;\; x\neq 0.
\end{equation}

I did some research and found that when $C$ is symmetric, $\mu$ define a norm at the space. But in my case, $C$ is not symmetric.

Another thing that may help is that: Let $x \in R^n$, $x \neq 0$, so the segment 0x intersect the boundary $\Sigma$ in exactly one point $x'$. So 
\begin{equation}
\mu_C(x) = \frac{d(0,x)}{d(0,x')} = \frac{\|x\|}{\|x'\|}.
\end{equation}
But I don't know how to differentiate $x'$.

Thank you for the help.